# Templatd lambda calling templated lambda (C++20) doesn't work with clang 12 / 13

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider this code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    static
    auto lA = []<bool FLAG_A, bool FLAG_B>( unsigned a ) -> unsigned
    {
        return (unsigned)FLAG_A + FLAG_B + a;
    };
    static
    auto lB = []<bool FLAG_A, bool FLAG_B>( unsigned a ) -> unsigned
    {
        return lA.template operator ()<FLAG_A, FLAG_B>( a );
    };
    using fn_t = function<unsigned ( unsigned )>;
    fn_t fn = bind( &decltype(lB)::template operator ()<false, false>, &lB, placeholders::_1 );
}
```

This compiles without any problems with MSVC 2019, but clang 12 / 13 gives the following errors:

```
test.cpp(11,12): error: multiple overloads of '__invoke' instantiate to the same signature 'auto (unsigned int) const -> unsigned int'
        auto lA = []<bool FLAG_A, bool FLAG_B>( unsigned a ) -> unsigned
                  ^
test.cpp(11,12): note: in instantiation of member class '' requested here
test.cpp(21,42): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'main(int, char **)::(anonymous class)::operator()<false, false>' requested here
        fn_t fn = bind( &decltype(lB)::template operator ()<false, false>, &lB, placeholders::_1 );
                                                ^
test.cpp(11,12): note: previous implicit declaration is here
        auto lA = []<bool FLAG_A, bool FLAG_B>( unsigned a ) -> unsigned
                  ^
```

gcc 11 also compiles the code without any errors. Is there a way to make the code to work with clang also without any elaborate workarounds ?

Comment: Clang 13 works [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6ra5rrqP4) (clang 12.0.1 produces ICE).

Comment: Oh, you're right ! It's only with clang-cl, the MSVC-conformant version.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: FYI: if you have to do this: `decltype(lB)::template operator ()`, you shouldn't be using a lambda at all. Just make a regular template function and move on with your life.

Answer (score 0):

There is still [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) (and even
`std::bool_constant` in your case) to allow deduction:

```
static auto lA = []<bool FLAG_A, bool FLAG_B>(std::bool_constant<FLAG_A>,
                                              std::bool_constant<FLAG_B>,
                                              unsigned a ) -> unsigned
{
    return (unsigned)FLAG_A + FLAG_B + a;
};
static
auto lB = []<bool FLAG_A, bool FLAG_B>( unsigned a ) -> unsigned
{
    return lA(std::bool_constant<FLAG_A>{}, std::bool_constant<FLAG_B>{}, a);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sno6bPG4a).